# wanting to position the image that appears when a different image is hovered over

Tags: css, image, hover, position

So I am wanting to change the position of an image that appears with the hover effect. Right now the image kind of just goes under the first image that holds the hover effect. I am struggling with this hardcore. I have tried positioning it and floating it and just simple left:90px or right:90px but the image that shows upon hovering doesn't budge. Here is a jsfiddle. The images are broken but you can get the jist. https://jsfiddle.net/k0fvbcno/ Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div id="pain1">
    <img class="pain1" src="images/painspot.png">
    <img class="shoulder" src="images/shoulder.png">
</div>  

<div id="pain2">
    <img class="pain2" src="images/painspot.png">
    <img class="back" src="images/back.png">
</div>

<div id="pain3">
    <img class="pain3" src="images/painspot.png">
    <img class="hip" src="images/hip.png">
</div>


#pain1 {
 position: absolute;
 left: 710px;
 top: 220px;
 margin: auto;
}

.shoulder {
 display: none;
}

.pain1:hover + .shoulder {
 display: inline;   
}

.pain1:hover{
 border: 3px solid transparent;
 display: block;    
}

#pain2 {
 position: absolute;
 left: 627px;
 top: 390px;
 margin: auto;
}

.back {
  display: none;
}

.pain2:hover + .back{
  display: inline;
}

.pain2:hover{
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  display: block;   
}

#pain3 {
 position: absolute;
 left: 680px;
 top: 425px;
}

.hip {
  display: none;    
}

.pain3:hover + .hip{
  display: inline;  
}

.pain3:hover {
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  display: block;   
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve a simple hover effect? Can the images be css `background-images`?

Comment: The hover effect I have working. What I am wanting to do is adjust the position of the image that appears upon hover. Will making them background images make a difference for that?

Comment: A simple `hover` effect can be achieved very simple with `background-images`. Pleas take a look at this. https://jsfiddle.net/dLrandfs/ is this what you after?

Comment: No I am sorry. I guess I am not wording it correctly. I have the hover working, I do not need help with that. My issue is that the image that appears from the hover effect needs to have it's position changed and I am having trouble with that. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally. I needed to use position absolute and that finally enabled me to position the image that appeared when the hover effect was in use. Thanks!